# how to make avd x86 work with windows hypervisor platform?

Tags: android, amd-processor

I have an AMD CPU. And I'm sure Hyper-V and windows-hypervisor-platform is enabled. But when I open the AVD x86 and it tell me need HAXM.

How could I do with this problem?

Comment: Check: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html and make sure you are follow the AMD related stuff at the bottom of the article.

Comment: hi sir, I had checked this article before I asked for help here. my cpu is r7 3700x and android studio version: 3.5; avd is 29.3, hyper-v and hypervisor-platform are alse enabled

Comment: Okay, version of OS / how much RAM in machine, check BIOS so that Virtualization or SVM is enabled, rebooted?, what are the results of https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-check

Comment: In my AVD dir this command worked . And I got this: accel: 6 GVM is not installed on this machine accel

Comment: I would check that you motherboard BIOS is up to date and configured correctly for virtualization. However I did find this: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html which means that perhaps you are encountering those "compatibility" issues and may wish to try the "AMD Hypervisor"

Comment: Yeah, AMD Hypervisor worked. And give me a big big "blue screen". I'm sure there is some "compatibility" issues there.I gave it up now. And thanks for your help.

Comment: All I can suggest is review the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 for similar problems and post with as much detail as possible if you do.

Comment: Fine. I will do it.